# make new posts loaded with infinitscroll.js load with their script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I'm using infinitscroll.js with wordpress for posts pagination.

in my content-post-audio.php I'm using a script to call jplayer.js (a script to create HTML audio player) when infinitscroll load new posts all audio type posts that have the jplayer call loads but without the jplayer call.

I tried to make infinitscroll to load my script but the script must load in every post separatly because it uses the post unique ID. this is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   setTimeout(function() {
      if($().jPlayer) {
      $("#jquery_jplayer_<?php echo $post_id;?>").jPlayer({ready:function(){
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            <?php if($mp3 != '') : ?>
            mp3: "<?php echo $mp3; ?>",
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($ogg != '') : ?>
            oga: "<?php echo $ogg; ?>",
            <?php endif; ?>
            end:""});
    },
    swfPath: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/scripts",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_interface_<?php echo $post_id; ?>",
    supplied: "<?php if($ogg != '') : ?>oga,<?php endif; ?>
                       <?php if($mp3 !='') : ?>mp3, <?php endif; ?> all"});

    }}, 100);
    });
</script>
```

Any help to make new audio posts loaded by infinitscroll load with there jplayer call??

Comment: is your problem that jPlayer is not binded to newly added posts?

Comment: the problem is that jplayer call in each audio type post is gone.

Comment: does the infinitescroll provide a callback for which you can then re-call your script?

Comment: sorry for the late response, yes it provides a call back but as you can see ( $("#jquery_jplayer_<?php echo $post_id;?>").jplayer ) the call uses $post_id

Answer (score 0):

had a similar issue with audio.js and simple old WordPress pagination. (no infinite scroll) - fix was pretty simple changed the preload attribute to none on the html5 audio tag and viola.... works like a charm.

I have absolutely no idea if you can apply this sort of option in jPlayer, but for the html5 version of the player, at least, it must be loading audio tags, and I assume should be something available in the plugin options.